# javascript regular expression - how to allow only one hyphen?

Tags: javascript

I have the following jscript code:

```
 var email = /^[a-z0-9'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?$/;

  if (s.match(email)) {
        return true;
  } else {
        return false;
  }
```

Now the end users are saying that they want "-" in the local part of the email address.  (i didn't even know that was legit)
But I need to prevent multiple hyphens I think - as per http://rumkin.com/software/email/rules.php
And also I don't think it can start with a hyphen.

But i'm not sure how to change this code to accomplish that.

**What I've tried**

```
var email = /^[a-z0-9'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.\-[a-z0-9'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?$/;
```

That allows me to enter a hyphen, but it doesn't limit it to one.

Comment: Do not make e-mail verification unnecessarily complex. As you saw in that page, there are many rules and exceptions. If you just check for something like... "@.*\." you'll do enough to prevent a couple of user errors. If you absolutely, positively, MUST verify an address... send an e-mail!

Comment: Nothing forbids multiple hyphens in the link you provided; it only says that there must be at least one character (implying even "--@example.com" should be a valid address).

Comment: I agree with @Tordek .Relying solely on validation of email addresses with regex is a bad idea.

Comment: Also, if you need to perform complicated validation with lots of arbitrary rules, a regex is probably not a good idea; you'll be better server by defining a `isValidEmail` function that performs each necessary check... but still, really, just send an email.

Comment: Thanks guys.  the best way to validate would be try to send an email to the account right?

Answer (score 0):

You are not restricted to do everything in one regex:

```
var email = /^[a-z0-9'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?$/;
if (!s.match(email)) return false;

if (s[0] == '-') return false;
if (s[s.length-1] == '-') return false;
if (s.indexOf('--') != -1) return false;
return true;
```